# How to include MapView in SherlockFragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, actionbarsherlock

I have the following:

1) `MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity`

2) `MyMapFragment extends SherlockFragment`

3) In `MyMapFragment` xml file I have a `MapView` with a correct apiKey

4) I have added **actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar** to my project's build path

So I'm doing:

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, new MyMapFragment());
```

And I'm getting exception as follows:

> 11-02 13:56:43.826: E/AndroidRuntime(28466): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to specify an API Key for
>   each MapView.  See the MapView documentation for details.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the ActionBarSherlock Plugin: Maps, Jake Warton says explicitly:

> Note: This does not provide support for placing a MapView in
>   fragments.

See https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has made ot for me:

http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/howto-actionbarsherlock-mapfragment-listfragment/